# Can you add a new line to a list box?

Tags: c#, listbox

I have 3 text boxes which then needs to be passed to a 1 line on a list box when you click add.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/97CKW.png

But when I click add on a list box it will show the information on a new line every time.

I have tried this with a richtextbox, but it is not working as well.I have also done some research and found out that it is possible on a listbox but you need to add something to my code.

My code so far:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal iQuantity;
    decimal iPrice;
    decimal Fullprice = 0;

    string Product = cmbItem.Text;
    string Quantity = txtQuantity.Text;
    string Price = txtPrice.Text;

    decimal.TryParse(Quantity, out iQuantity);
    decimal.TryParse(Price, out iPrice);

    if (iQuantity <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Quantity larger than 0", "Quantity", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if (iPrice <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid price above 0", "Price", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        Fullprice = iPrice * iQuantity;
        rtbBasket.AppendText(string.Format("{0} {1} £{2} £{3}",Product,iQuantity,iPrice,Fullprice + Environment.NewLine));
    }
}
```

Comment: the smartest way would be to create an `itemclass` with your three properties. use a `List<itemclass>` to add and remove your items. use a listbox and set its `datasource property` to your list.

Comment: @Koryu I am quite new have you got a reference to help with this or may you provide some help? Thanks

Comment: sure. check my answer, using a list and databinding is best practise imo. it will also make it more easy editing and removing items.

Answer (score 0):

```
rtbBasket.AppendText(string.Format("{0}
```

You are missing some code above?

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal iQuantity;
    decimal iPrice;
    decimal Fullprice = 0;

    string Product = cmbItem.Text;
    string Quantity = txtQuantity.Text;
    string Price = txtPrice.Text;

    decimal.TryParse(Quantity, out iQuantity);
    decimal.TryParse(Price, out iPrice);

    if (iQuantity <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter Quantity larger than 0", "Quantity", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else if (iPrice <= 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid price above 0", "Price", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    else
    {
        Fullprice = iPrice * iQuantity;
                                                                                    £{2}                           £{3}",Product,iQuantity,iPrice,Fullprice + Environment.NewLine));
    }

rtbBasket.AppendText(Product + " " + Quantity + " " Price);


}
```

Comment: Thanks for doing some code, if you scroll across you can see I have tabbed in to move the data across haha, also your code at the bottom doesn't work for me it says that 'Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as a statement'

Answer (score 0):

You can build an string and then pass it to the items collection of the listbox.

Check out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx
and 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope this helps and btw next time try to tackle with it and look for reference(google maybe).

Comment: thanks for the reference, I did check Google but the answers there said I could not get this completed.

Answer (score 0):

ok for that u just have to do like that

ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();

for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)

{

```
  listBox1.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's a good example to get started in object oriented programming.  You could just add items as strings to a listbox by `listbox1.Items.Add(string)`.

But best practise would be to use an custom item class to store your item information.
Use these items in a BindingList and bind it to a ListBox. This will make it also a lot easier to remove or to edit items.

```
 public class CustomItem 
 {

    private string sProduct;
    public string Product
    {
      get { return sProduct; }
      set { sProduct = value; }
    }

    // i used int instead of string here
    private int nQuantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
      get { return nQuantity; }
      set { nQuantity = value; }
    }
    // i used double instead of string here    
    private double dPrice;
    public double Price
    {
      get { return dPrice; }
      set { dPrice = value; }
    }

    // simple constructor
    public CustomItem(string sProduct, int nQuantity, double dPrice)
    {
      this.Product = sProduct;
      this.Quantity = nQuantity;
      this.Price = dPrice;
    }

    // the listbox will use this method to show the item
    public override string ToString()
    {
      return sProduct + " " + nQuantity.ToString() + " " + dPrice.ToString() ;
    }
  }
```

example how to use in a simple form with a listbox and a button to add

```
using System.ComponentModel;    
//...
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    // declare your custom binding list 
    BindingList<CustomItem> myList = null;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      // initialize your list.
      myList = new BindingList<CustomItem>();    
      // binding your list to your listbox                 
      listBox1.DataSource = myList;
    }


    // a simple button to add items, parse your values here
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      myList.Add(new CustomItem("Productname",10, 24.99));           
    }


  }
```

even better would be to use a listview or datagridview. datagridview will work similar listview is a bit tricky.